# C# cannot read from read-only Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have a folder on my PC containing multiple Excel spreadsheets that are all marked as read-only. 
The folder is synced to my company's Sharepoint via OneDrive.

When I try to programmatically read data from one of these sheets via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, I keep getting the `You cannot use this command on a protected sheet` error.

Here's the code I use to open the file:

```
public ExcelReader(String filePath)
{
        this.filePath = filePath;
        FileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        app = new Excel.Application();
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, true); //open in read only
}

public void openSheet(String sheet)
{
        SheetName = sheet;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet];
        Excel.Range last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        ColumnsTotal = last.Column;
        RowsTotal = last.Row;
}
```

The line that throws the exception is `Excel.Range last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);`.

I figured that since I explicitly tell the Workbook to open in Read-only mode, and since I never modify the content of these files, the fact that files are read-only shouldn't be a problem.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I read the content of these files without unprotecting them (I can't do that for security reasons)?

Comment: Other than being read-only seems like the sheet is protected with password? is that the case?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava No, the files themselves do not need a separate password to access, but access to company SHP is restricted to certain users. Don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Does the error go away - if you change the Excel file to not be ReadOnly (Right Click > Properties)

Comment: If I recall correctly, Excel protection (using a password) prohibits against making changes to cells that are marked 'Locked', it does not prohibit opening the sheet. I read in other places also that `SpecialCells` does not work in Protected sheets (e.g. here: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/finding-the-last-cell-in-a-protected-sheet.2749348/) unless you specify the password.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks, you were right that the problem was caused by SpecialCells usage. When I removed the last three lines the errors stopped.